# Relationship between compact operators and coefficients tending to zero

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

While reading the solutions of an exercise, I found the following statement:

[image: proof]

Where $d$ is some operator and $I$ is the identity operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$. I managed to get the formula for $(I-dd^*)g$ that is written below, however, I couldn't draw the same conclusion. 
I checked in the lecture notes and I couldn't find any reference regarding the relationship between Fourier coefficients of a function in the image of an operator, and the operator being compact. If it helps, It is pretty easy to show that this operator is bounded.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is quite a definition : $T$ is compact iff there is a sequence of finite dimensional operators $T_n$ such that $\|T g - T_n g \| < A_n\|g\|$ and $A_n \to 0$. Now that $Tg = \sum_k c_k \langle g,e_k \rangle e_k$ with $c_k \to 0$ and $(e_k)$ orthonormal implies $\|Tg - T_ng\| = \|\sum_{|k| > n}  c_k \langle g,e_k \rangle e_k \| < ...$

Comment: @reuns thanks for your comment! Can you please cite any theorem and / or give me any link to it?

Comment: You can take it as the definition of compact operators. The other definitions are more abstract and the proof they are equivalent are not hard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space

Comment: @reuns Thanks! Do you mind writing up an answer and expanding a bit more your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{ e_k \}_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}$. Your operator is the same as the diagonal operator $D$ given by
$$
            Df = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+k^2}\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k.
$$

To show that $D$ is compact, let $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be bounded sequence in $\mathcal{H}$ with bound $M$; it must be shown that $\{ Df_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Every coordinate sequence $\{ \langle f_n,e_k\rangle\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by $M$; this bound holds for all $k$. Using Cantor diagonalization, there is a subsequence $\{ f_{n_m} \}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim_{m}\langle f_{n_m},e_k\rangle$ converges for every $k$ to some limit $\alpha_{k}$. The sequence $\{\alpha_k\}$ is uniformly bounded by $M$; therefore $y=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha_k}{1+k^2} e_k \in \mathcal{H}$. And,
$$
      \left\|Df_{n_m}-y\right\|^2 
     = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+k^2}|\langle f_{n_m},e_k\rangle-\alpha_k|^2
$$
converges to $0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$. (You can apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence Theorem applied to a discrete measure, or you can argue directly.) Hence,
$$
      \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}Df_{n_m}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+k^2}\alpha_k e_k
$$
So $D$ is compact.